# Recovering a lost partition table on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, partition-recovery

First of all sorry that I cannot provide additional screenshots and codes (the reason is, why I am here).

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad which is equipped with two storage disks, a 500GB HDD and a 128GB SSD. Yesterday, after I tried to boot the system, the Lenovo logo came up as usual then I saw an unusual blank/black screen for 5-6 seconds and finally a "Boot option" menu showed up. I chose the proper boot device (which is the SSD), again the system showed me 5-6 seconds of blank screen and again the "Boot option" menu came up.

I used a windows recovery USB and booted the system using that. Using "diskpart" I found out that the 500GB HDD is safe and sound but the partition table of 128GB SSD is totally lost. When I tried to run "list vol" in "diskpart", it replied with ~"No volume/partition exists".

I tried few other tools, but since there is no partition, none of the normal recovery tools can actually do anything (they need a partition to work on).
Then as the last option I booted the system using "Active @ boot disk". It had a tool which is called "Active@ Partition Recovery", in this tool I can see both disks, the 500GB HDD has all of its partitions but there is nothing under 128GB SSD (it only shows the name of disk without any partition).

Then I ran the "Active@ Partition Recovery" on the 128GB SSD disk, after few hours of processing, the result was thousands of error logs which said ~"Bad sector detected", ~"cannot read section".

Then I tried to use CHKDSK to recover the bad sectors, but as I mentioned earlier, CHKDSK did not have the 128GB SSD in its known partitions. Because there is no partition on the disk.

So, now I am totally out of idea, could you help me with any possibility which comes to your mind? I have to recover the data on this partition, it is vital.

Again, sorry that I didn't provide any screenshots to describe the problem better and also sorry if this is a duplicate question. I tried my best to search the forum before submitting this question but unfortunately I couldn't find any answer. There are similar Q but the A was not useful for me.

Thank you all

-UPDATE1-
The last backup is for 72 hours before the crash.

-UPDATE2-
I managed to take some screenshots.

[This is how CrystalDiskInfo describes the faulty disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2vVb.jpg)

[When I am trying to initialize the disk in disk-management tool, a read error message stops the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoF0R.jpg)

Comment: Just for clarity, you say that the data "is vital", but are we to assume that you have no current backup?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, Unfortunately the latest backup is for 72 hours before the crash and I really hope to preserve changes which have been made on folders during the last 72 hours.

Comment: You should make a sector-level copy of the malfunctioning SSD and store it somewhere safe, perhaps on the HDD. On Linux, I would recommend GNU ddrescue; for Windows, I don't know what tools are available. That won't magically bring back any of the data, but it will ensure that it doesn't suffer from further degredation, or that you break things further in trying to fix this and can't go back.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, Thanks for reminder.
I tried some tools (including hddguru) but even in this case I only receive "Read error Occurred - Uncorrectable error".

Comment: If even software designed to try to recover as much data as possible from the drive is unable to read anything, then unfortunately you may be out of luck.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, Thanks for your reply. I'm starting to think so, but I really hope to find a way.

DISKPART is also not able to see anything: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rbmeP.jpg

Comment: I also tried "Paragon partition manager 15", it couldn't detect the faulty hard disk. Exited with "I/O read write error".

Comment: "Remo Recover" has been also tested.
The disk couldn't be found.

Comment: Another friend suggested "HDDRawCopy", no success though.

Comment: "HDClone" has been also checked. Without any success.

Comment: "Partition FindAndMount" is one of the few software, which could at least detect the faulty hard disk, but unfortunately no success at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do believe that you may be out of luck, and will have to resort to restoring your most recent backup.

As I suggested in the comments, the first step when experiencing problems like what you are seeing (unless you can trivially reconstruct all the data on the drive) should be to make a sector-level copy of the problematic drive. On Linux you might use GNU ddrescue (comes with many distributions and live CDs) for such purposes; for Windows, I cannot recommend any particular software, but search for *disk imager* and the likes. Make sure to image the whole drive, not just any one partition. That way, you can experiment without risk of further data loss; if you break something, you can start all over and be back where you were originally.

The fact that in your case [DISKPART finds no partitions on the SSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbmeP.jpg) and that many operations that should be trivial are throwing I/O errors, unfortunately points toward a non-functional SSD.

**If you *really* need the recent changes back it may be possible to enlist the services of a data recovery company, but the most practical answer at this point probably is to restore that 72 hours old backup onto a new drive.**

At least you *have* a reasonably recent backup. A lot of people who find themselves with a non-functional storage device aren't that fortunate.

Comment: Thanks @michael-Kjörling,
Although we could not recover the data, but your reply actually answered the question, so I chose this as the answer.